# What is "national network news"?

Tags: meaning

I was reading the ranking of news sources by popularity in the US which is *local TV, national network news, online news, radio news, local newspaper, national newspaper*.

I don't understand what national network news exactly is. I searched it online and it gave me a name of a weekly newspaper, [*National Network*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Network_(newspaper)). But isn't it again a kind of national newspaper? That aside, it wasn't written in capital letters on the list so I figured it's probably not the newspaper. What does it mean? What means of media is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "national network news" refers to news programs aired by TV stations which are located throughout the country but belong to a single corporation such as CBS or NBC, and having a national (and sometimes international) focus, as distinct from those news programs which concentrate on the news from a single city and its suburbs. National network news programs are aired nationally. There are half a dozen major national network news outlets competing for a slice of the demographic.  With local news, each city has its own news team (anchor, reporters, weather guy or weather gal, etc) and the news is parochial. Each city may have two or three local news outlets competing for viewers.

Comment: I see, as opposed to local TV stations. + 1 Thank you :)